# How to append to XML file using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have two XML files. I want to append a node from the 1st XML to 2nd XML.

This my 1st XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UUT>
    <Auto>
        <Process>AutoGM</Process>
    </Auto>

    <UnitInfo>
        <SN>5CD1234567</SN>
        <MAC>1062E5961370</MAC>
        <SSID>1062E5961370</SSID>
    </UnitInfo> 
</UUT>
```

I want to append this node to my 2nd xml.

```xml
<UnitInfo>
    <SN>5CD1234567</SN>
    <MAC>1062E5961370</MAC>
    <SSID>1062E5961370</SSID>
</UnitInfo>
```

This is my second XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PC>
    <Platform>
        <SSID1>8549</SSID1><SSID2>5678</SSID2>
    </Platform>                
</PC>
```

The 2nd XML should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PC>
    <Platform>
        <SSID1>8549</SSID1><SSID2>5678</SSID2>
    </Platform> 
    
    <UnitInfo>
    <SN>5CD1234567</SN>
    <MAC>1062E5961370</MAC>
    <SSID>1062E5961370</SSID>
    </UnitInfo>
         
</PC>
```

I tried this

#### Updated

```bsh
[xml]$Read_JOB = Get-Content "D:\Process\first.xml" 
[xml]$Read_UUT = Get-Content "D:\Process\second.xml"

$Read_JOB.JOB.AppendChild($Read_JOB.ImportNode(($Read_UUT.UUT.UUTInfo), $true))
$Read_JOB.Save("D:\Process\second.xml")
```

But the output is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PC>
    <Platform>
        <SSID1>8549</SSID1><SSID2>5678</SSID2>
    </Platform>   
<UUT>
    <Auto>
        <Process>AutoGM</Process>
    </Auto>

    <UnitInfo>
        <SN>5CD1234567</SN>
        <MAC>1062E5961370</MAC>
        <SSID>1062E5961370</SSID>
    </UnitInfo> 
</UUT>
             
</PC>
```

This is work, I updated

Comment: `$Read_UUT.UUT.UUTInfo` -> `$Read_UUT.SelectSingleNode('//UnitInfo')`

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point correctly, you want to load 1.xml, 2.xml and append them in 3.xml.

Something to start with:

```cs
$output = 'path\output.xml'
# Document creation
[xml]$Final = New-Object System.Xml.Finalument
$Final.LoadXml("<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"utf-8`"?><PC></PC>")

# Creation of the first node
$FE1 = $Final.CreateElement("Platform")

# Creation of a sub node LOOP through other file
$SE1 = $Final.CreateElement("SSID1")
$SET1 = $Final.CreateTextNode("8541")
$SE1.AppendChild($SET1)
$FE1.AppendChild($SE1)

$SE1 = $Final.CreateElement("SSID2")
$SET1 = $Final.CreateTextNode("8549")
$SE1.AppendChild($SET1)
$FE1.AppendChild($SE1)

# Add the node to the document
$Final.LastChild.AppendChild($FE1);

# Store to a file 
$Final.Save("$output")

<#
FE1 = First Element
SE1 = Second Element
SET1 = Text for "Second Element 
#>
```

You Just need to call the variables in a loop for each element.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me using your example XML data.

```
$XML1 = [xml](Get-Content D:\Process\first.xml)
$NodeToAppend = $XML1.SelectSingleNode('//UnitInfo')
$XMLToUpdate = [xml](Get-Content D:\Process\second.xml)
$XMLToUpdate.PC.AppendChild($XMLToUpdate.ImportNode($NodeToAppend,$true))
$XMLToUpdate.Save("D:\Process\third.xml") # This can be second.xml
```